# PHP retrieving data from 30 million records

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am using the below given custom query in my moodle site and its working fine but now the total records in mdl_user_enrollments table is 30 million which take time to return the result to my frond end screen. Please let me know how to make it fast.

Query given below

```
select t1.userid,t2.courseid AS course_id, t1.timestart AS subscription_start, t1.timeend AS subscription_end,t1.timecreated AS timecreated,t1.timemodified AS timemodified, t3.id AS quiz_id,

t3.name AS quiz_name from mdl_user_enrolments t1 

join  mdl_enrol t2 on t1.userid=$user_id and  t1.enrolid = t2.id

join mdl_quiz t3 on t3.course = t2.courseid
```

Explain output

```
Explain mdl_user_enrolments result

Field          Type       Null    Key    Default      Extra     
id           bigint(10)    NO     PRI     NULL         auto_increment 
status       bigint(10)    NO      0    
enrolid      bigint(10)    NO     MUL     NULL  
userid       bigint(10)    NO     MUL     NULL  
timestart    bigint(10)    NO      0 
timeend      bigint(10)    NO   2147483647 
modifierid   bigint(10)    NO      MUL      0   
timecreated  bigint(10)    NO       0   
timemodified bigint(10)    NO       0
```

Analyze table mdl_user_enrolments result

Table                                Op      Msg_type   Msg_text 
eLearningDev_v1.mdl_user_enrolments analyze    status     OK

Size of table mdl_user_enrolments 910 MB

Comment: use indexing and what is database engine?

Comment: indexing is there

Comment: indexing is there
InnoDB  DEFAULT  Supports transactions, row-level locking, and fore...  YES  YES  YES

Comment: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1  SIMPLE  t1  ref  mdl_userenro_enruse_uix,mdl_userenro_enr_ix,mdl_us...  mdl_userenro_use_ix  8  const  164  
1  SIMPLE  t2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,mdl_enro_cou_ix  PRIMARY  8  eLearningDev_v1.t1.enrolid  1  
1  SIMPLE  t3  ref  mdl_quiz_cou_ix  mdl_quiz_cou_ix  8  eLearningDev_v1.t2.courseid  1

Comment: when I put explain my query in the quetion I got the above result

Comment: PHP retrieving 30million records... thers a limit to which u can be efficient with PHP, you may consider pulling the records in bits like using datatables and fetching bits at a time or use some other language that is less likely to crash on that volume -- python, C...

Comment: I think its better to use a powerful cache system to avoid querying data from your database every time. you can use `memcached` or even more powerful ones like `redis`

Comment: The query looks normal. If scanning large dataset is the real problem here then only infrastructure scaling can solve this. How many rows does this query return?

Comment: query returns only 1050 records from this 30 million records

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.userid,t2.courseid AS course_id, t1.timestart AS subscription_start, t1.timeend AS subscription_end,t1.timecreated AS timecreated,t1.timemodified AS timemodified, t3.id AS quiz_id,    
t3.name AS quiz_name from mdl_user_enrolments t1     
LEFT join  mdl_enrol AS  t2 on t1.userid=$user_id and  t1.enrolid = t2.id    
LEFT join mdl_quiz AS  t3 on t3.course = t2.courseid
```

Hopefully this will works for you.

Comment: query is executing but how to make it fast when it retrieve data and to my frontend from a table having 30 million data

Comment: Ooooh! omg 
you have to set cron file  for this query which work twine in day and store in new table and therefor you can optimized the time.

Comment: When a users logins to the site I am retrieving the records using this showing the result, as execution takes a lot of time this is loading very slowly. but same query I have added for webservice app and same result they are getting in 30 seconds